# In the context of government policies, can a progressive tax have no exemptions?

Tags: taxes

Does having exemptions define (partially or entirely) what progressive tax means? I just thought exemptions don't have anything to do with tax being flat or progressive. Is there any credible reference you could point me to for this matter?

Comment: Do you have a source for the initial claim?  It's not really clear what you are asking and a reference may help clarify it.

Comment: Given that "tax + 'naturally exempting'" Google search is practically empty, this doesn't seem to be a real term in the first place, so it's impossible to answer withoout explanation of what you mean by "naturally exempting"

Comment: I edited the question and removed the parts that might be causing the confusion.

Comment: I was actually arguing with someone. I just thought if we want to eliminate exemptions, we can do so without turning to flat tax (we currently have progressive tax in place). And then he said no, progressive tax is naturally exempting.

Comment: If you want to adjust taxable income without calling them tax exemptions, sure, why not?

Answer (score 3):

I think your friend is applying the term "exemption" to mean that certain tax payers may be taxed at a reduced rate. That concept is intrinsic to a *progressive tax system.*

**But** the term *tax exemption* generally refers to a statutory exception to a general rule rather than the mere absence of taxation in particular circumstances ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tax_exemption)). It would *not* be correct to say that lower-income taxpayers are *tax exempt* from paying the higher rates of the upper-income groups.

So when used correctly, whether a government allows tax exemptions or not has nothing to do with the *tax system* being flat or progressive.